# Image Noise Detection Using MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, noise, denoising

I want to implement the following algorithm. Let  $I$  denote  noisy  image  and  for  each  pixel of  $I$  is represented by $I(x,y)$. A Sliding window of size $3\times3$ centered at $I(x, y)$ is defined. At first we estimate that the center pixel of window is noise or not. To differ the noise and signal, we calculate the mean ($m$) and standard deviation ($s$) of the window. If the pixel is between $m-s$ and $m+s$ then it is a signal otherwise noise and we will apply weiner Filter.

Algorithm:

```
1.  Read an Image I.
2.  Take a Sliding Window or Mask of size 3X3.
3.  Calculate the Mean (m) and Standard deviation (s) from the Mask.
4.  Calculate the threshold as follows 
         t1 = m-s and t2 = m+s

5.  IF     t1 <= I(x,y) and  I(x,y)  <= t2 THEN

           Result(x,y) = I(x,y)
    ELSE
        Result(x, y) = weiner2(I(x,y)

6.  Repeat the step 3 , 4 and 5 on Entire Image.
7.  Display the Resultant Image.
```

First, I tried to implement this algorithm for median filter, so that I can extend it to other filters such as wiener, anisotropic diffusion,butterworth etc.  I did implement it correctly with the help of 'tbirdal'. Thank you 'tbirdal'. But I am unable to extend the implementation for other filters.

**I don't want to use loop.. Because it takes more time to run .. 20 mins to run a $512 \times 512$ image.. I want to implement this using functions such as nlfilter, imfilter etc **
Program:

```
A=imread('npan3.jpg');


fun = @(x) noisedetect_2(x(:));
B = nlfilter(A,[3 3],fun);

imshow(A), figure, imshow(B, [])
```

The `noisedetect_2` function is given as

```
function nd=noisedetect_2(sub)
sub=vec2mat(sub,3);
[row col]=size(sub);
%siz=size(sub)
s=std2(sub);
m=mean2(sub);
t1=m-s;
t2=m+s;
nd=zeros(row,col);

if (sub(2,2)>=t1 && sub(2,2)<=t2)
    nd=sub;
else    
    nd=wiener2(sub);
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in nlfilter (line 75)
        b(i,j) = feval(fun,x,params{:});

Error in nd_test_2 (line 10)
B = nlfilter(A,[3 3],fun);
```

I understand what the error means. the `nlfilter` is expecting single value but the function returns $3\times3$ matrix. How to solve this issue?. I just want to apply any filter only when the pixel falls out of the range $t_1$ and $t_2$ because it is considered as noisy pixel. Otherwise, it is retained as such because it is considered as noisefree pixel.

Please help me implement the algorithm.

Comment: Migration of answered questions is generally frowned upon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/131640

Comment: How to migrated?

Comment: Read the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @PremnathD, Could you please review my answer? If it fits, please mark it.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it differently altogether.
Since applying the Wiener filter is pretty "cheap" I would create an Image called `mWienerFilter`.
Then:

```
vNoisePixels = (abs(I -  mMeanImage) > noiseThr);
I(vNoisePixels) = mWienerFilter(vNoisePixels);
```

That would be the best thing to do in my opinion.